# My Galaxy Tab S is stuck in boot with no OS

Tags: samsung, operating-system

My tablet was not working correctly so i decided to do a factory reset when it booted up it was freezing so I powered it off and entered recovery mode but then I accidentally deleted the OS. This was a huge mistake TWRP was giving me options of booting it into download mode, power off or restarting it. After trying to restart it and powering it offit kept going back to TWRP so I decided to go into download mode it entered without giving me the option off restarting or continuing i had no idea what to do so I opened Odin on my PC and applied a 'cf auto root' because i had done that the last time I seen the download mode. It worked and then it rebooted and now its stuck in the 'Samsung Galaxy Tab S SM-T700 powered by android screen'. The tablet is 11 months old and I still have a warranty I don't know if it is void or not. someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Download the stock rom from Samsung or any custom rom from XDA that you like.

Go to recovery.

Wipe /system, /data and cache.

Install the zip file from within the recovery.

Wipe cache and Dalvik.

Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have warranty use it, that's the easiest way.
If not:

> Go to SamMobile Firmwares. Enter T700 in the search box. Click the search icon (the magnifying glass). Choose the country. Download the file. (You'll have to create a free account to download it.)
>   Open Odin as Administrator, http://www.androidofficer.com/2015/01/t700xxu1anl2-android-442-xxu1anl2.html, but add all the files. The APxxx file goes into the AP slot, the BLxxx file goes into the BL slot, etc. (If the PIT button shows a file, there will be only one, so choose it. If not, leave it blank).
>   THEN Start Odin, and it should give you back your tab. (It'll take a while.) The instructions on that site are for updating an existing system, you have to flash the entire system. You're in a bootloop because the file the bootloader runs isn't there any more, and updating doesn't put that file on the phone because it's not one that gets updated.

Credit: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-tab-s-8-4/494657-i-deleted-my-samsung-galaxy-tab-s-os-how-can-i-get-back.html